# Easiest way to insert a table into another with conflicting auto-increment values?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have two tables that have a huge list of columns.  They are both the same structure, but different data.  However, both tables have an index/auto-increment column that might be similar.  Is there an easy way to run a command like this:

```
insert into table1 (select * from table2);
```

and have the insert ignore the auto-increment column from table 2?  To avoid an error if there's a similar-value in the index column of tables 1 and 2?  I want to copy everything over, and have new auto-increments for the table 2 data in table 1.

Alternatively, I don't care what the values are of the auto-increment index.  If there was a way to merge the two tables and then re-generate unique AI columns that would also work.

I am aware I could get around this by specifying each field individually in both tables and leaving out the auto-increment column.  I'm just wondering if there is an easier way to do this?  If there isn't, is there an easy way of generating the field list/statement?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most efficient way I know of right now.  Assuming the A.I. index is called "recno"

```
ALTER TABLE table1 DROP COLUMN recid;
ALTER TABLE table2 DROP COLUMN recid;
insert into table1 (select * from table2);
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD `recid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT [AFTER `column`], ADD PRIMARY KEY (`recid`);
ALTER TABLE table2 ADD `recid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT [AFTER `column`], ADD PRIMARY KEY (`recid`);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a way to do that.  The `*` in the SELECT list means "all columns" in ordinal position. There's not exception for columns that meet specified criteria.

The same is true for an omitted list of columns that we're inserting into... it's all of the columns.

The most efficient way (in terms of database resources) to accomplish the specified goal is to list the columns, and omit the auto_increment column from the list.

```
INSERT INTO t (b,c,d,e) SELECT b,c,d,e FROM s ;
```

We can get a list of columns names for a table from `information_schema.columns`...

For example, to get a list of the column names in table2:

```
SELECT c.column_name
  FROM information_schema.columns c
 WHERE c.table_schema = 'mydatabase'
   AND c.table_name   = 'table2'
 ORDER
    BY c.ordinal_position
```

To exclude the auto_increment column from the list, we can add a WHERE clause, that excludes that column by it's name

```
 WHERE c.column_name NOT IN ('my_autoincrement_column_name')
```

or we can check for `'auto_increment'` occurring the `EXTRA` column

```
 WHERE c.extra NOT LIKE '%auto_increment%'
```

---

To get a column list for each of the two tables, excluding the auto_increment columns, we could do something like this:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 16777216 ;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT('`',c.column_name,'`') 
         ORDER BY c.ordinal_position
         SEPARATOR ','
       ) AS `-- column_list`
  FROM information_schema.columns c
 WHERE c.table_schema = 'mydatabase'
   AND c.table_name IN ('table1','table2')
   AND c.extra NOT LIKE '%auto_increment%'
 GROUP
    BY c.table_schema
     , c.table_name
 ORDER
    BY c.table_schema
     , c.table_name
```

**EDIT**

I'd take the column lists, and build a SQL query.

If we're going to make changes to `table2` (dropping the auto_increment column as suggested in another answer to this question), and if we don't need to preserve the values in the column, the easiest change would be to just set all of the values in that column to NULL.

No need to modify table1.

We can remove the auto_increment attribute (and the NOT NULL constraint if that's specified) from the column in table2, and set the column to null. Assuming `ai` is the name of the auto_increment column, and assuming it's declared to be INT UNSIGNED datatype, we can do:

```
 ALTER TABLE `table2` CHANGE `ai` `ai` INT UNSIGNED COMMENT '' ;
 UPDATE `table2` SET `ai` = NULL ;
```

Then we can do an `INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2`

And then add back the auto_increment attribute to the column in table2.

This approach is more expensive (in terms of the database resources) than a single `INSERT ... SELECT`.

---

Generating a column list is an extra step, but the resulting operation would be much more efficient. We could generate a list of columns from just the source table, and then replace the column name with literal NULL value...

```
INSERT INTO t SELECT NULL,b,c,d FROM s;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive response.  Some good insight into table management.   I'm not sure that's necessarily an easier way, but it's informative.